# List of months and values from sql postgressql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can write query to get all months and values.
For example :

```
Value    Month
  1       January
  2       February
```

and so on...

Comment: Please explain what this means.  What do you mean "all month"?  How is "value" calculated?

Answer (score 1):

Using `generate_series`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s) AS value,
       TO_CHAR(s, 'Month') AS Month
FROM generate_series('2020-01-01'::date, '2020-12-31'::date, '1 month'::interval) s
```

---

```
SELECT s.value, 
       TO_CHAR('2020-01-01'::date + (s.value - 1) * '1 month'::interval, 'Month') AS month
FROM generate_series(1,12) s(value);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=81d8e14d493be476a2db038f7ca25fd8)**

Comment: this is only list of months, what about values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12....for months ?

Comment: @uzhas It is not an issue at all, either a ROW_NUMBER or generating series of number first instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `generate_series()` to get the month numbers and then with `TO_DATE()` and `TO_CHAR()` convert the numbers to month names:

```
SELECT Value, 
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(Value::text, 'MM'), 'Month') AS "Month"
FROM generate_series(1, 12) Value;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=54d960c2041cb2b8df51d60abddba3a3).